# Swiper.js loop doesn't work correct in angular

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I use swiper js in my angular project  and loop doesn't work.  If I use `slidesPerView: 4, loop: true`, it just doesn't loop at all.

Here's my code :

```js
const DEFAULT_SWIPER_CONFIG: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    // slidesPerView: 4,
    loopedSlides: 4,
    loop: true
};
```

```html
<swiper class="swiper" [config]="swiperConfigFavoritesGames" loop="true">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 game" *ngFor="let game of us.user.gamesArr">
       <div class="image-wrapper">                  
         <a routerLink="/games/{{game._id}}/{{game.urlFriendlyName|url}}">
            <img [src]="ts.getLocaleTranslate(game, 'thumb', 'defaultThumb')" alt="Game Photo"/>
            <div class="label" *ngIf="game.hot" translate>  Home.HOT </div>`
                 </a>
           </div>
       </div>
</swiper>
```

I tried to use `loopedSlides: 4` instead of `slidesPerView`  but in this case it scrolls to the last slide and then scrolls further to some white space with no slides at all, and doesn't return to first slide.

Comment: Please refer to this resource for potential answers to your query: [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912532/how-to-loop-slides-in-swiper-js-angular)